# How is this the chain rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm having a hard time seeing why this is the chain rule [source here]. I cahnged some of the symbols used in order to shorten the expression. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09055.pdf). Let $w' = w - \xi\nabla_w T(w, \alpha), \alpha)$

$$
\nabla_{\alpha}V(w - \xi\nabla_w T(w, \alpha), \alpha) = \nabla_\alpha V(w', \alpha) - \xi\nabla^2_{\alpha, w} T(w, \alpha) \nabla_{w'}V(w', \alpha)
$$

I don't see how the chain rule can get us from the LHS to the RHS...

Comment: Sorry but can you please clarify the notation - how to apply $\nabla$ to a tuple - $\nabla_\alpha(w', \alpha)$?

Comment: that is a typo, it should be the function $V$